# How to save Texture2D as image in gallery?

Tags: encode, texture2d

Let's say I have a 2D texture. How can I save it as a **PNG** or **JPG** image in unity. Please write the most common version, if possible with comments.

Answer (score 0):

[Texture2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.html) has a [EncodeToPNG](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG.html) and [EncodeToJPG](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToJPG.html) method.

Comment: I know it. Watch this.

this does not work in android

`public Save(){
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/image.png";
    bytes = FullImageTexture.EncodeToPNG();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
}`

Comment: picture does not appear on mobile devices
missing in the gallery and in emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.programname/files